# Why does exec(ping ip address) in php returns empty results?

Tags: exec, ping

In terminal, I can ping my routers 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.2 & 192.168.1.1 and get expected results.

I am working on Mac Monterey with Laravel/Laradock.

In PHP, I use

```
 echo exec("ping 192.168.1.3") or 
 exec("ping 192.168.1.3",$output,$result) then echo $output
```

In both case, I get an empty output & result 127.

I tried with an external IP address...

```
 192.44.136.114 – Telecom namibia
 197.221.2.113 - my server in South Africa
```

I also tried with

```
 -c 5 -n -i 1
```

same empty output & 127 result.

This looks pretty simple... but it does not work!

Help please...